# Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_query() on resource in line 30

Tags: php

It seems I am more annoyed about this problem which I can't figured out why this happens. Any help is much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
  <?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

```
  <body>

     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="">
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Date</th>
                              <th>User</th>
                              <th>Action</th>
                              </tr>                                         
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

              <?php
                     $query = $link->mysql_query("select * from  activity_log ORDER BY activity_log_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
                  while($row = $query->fetch()){
                ?>

                                <tr>
                                       <td><?php  echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                                       <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                                       <td><?php echo $row['action']; ?></td> 
                                </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is $link? What happens if you change $link->mysql_query to mysql_query ?

And you should have a look to PDO to handle mysql connections :-)
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: You're using the OOP structure of `Mysqli` with the procedural functions of `mysql_*()`. the two don't mix. Do __not__ use `mysql_*()` for new code. It is deprecated and __will be removed__ in the next release of PHP, due this year. Use `Mysqli`, or better `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from  activity_log ORDER BY activity_log_id DESC");
if (!$query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

then in while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

[Read The `mysql_query` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [Read The `mysql_fetch_assoc` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

> **Note**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

1. [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
2. [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from  activity_log ORDER BY activity_log_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

instead of

```
$query = $link->mysql_query("select * from  activity_log ORDER BY activity_log_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = $query->fetch()){
```